# mysql: database suddenly loading forever

Tags: mysql

so I downloaded a public database. example.myd (10.2GB), example.myi (9.7GB) example.frm (21KB). I simply installed xampp. Mysql, phpmyadmin etc working perfectly. I just put these 3 files into the database which I created and it worked fine. Loading time was like 2-3 seconds which are fully okay for that big of a database. Since yesterday when i started my computer and loaded everything up, the database wont load. I click on the database and its saying Loading forever. I did not change anything. (Maybe I did without knowing ha)

I reinstalled xampp. I redownloaded the database. I tried via VPS. I tried via RDP. Diffrent browsers. Everything is just loading forever. Anyone has an idea what the problem is and how to solve it? I really need the access to the database. Thank you

Comment: Those are "files"; they don't need to be loaded, simply moved into a directory _once_

Comment: @RickJames Yeah i did that. I somehow fixed it that the first 25 rows show. If I search for a certain row:
`#126 - Index for table '.\chris\101m.MYI' is corrupt; try to repair is`
How do I repair a MYI? Is there any tutorial? I found a program but that costs like 250€

Answer (score 0):

> #126 - Index for table '.\chris\101m.MYI' is corrupt; try to repair

```
USE chris;
REPAIR TABLE 101m;
```

Plan on converting from MyISAM to InnoDB so you won't ever have to do that again.

In the MyISAM engine, the table `101m` is represented by 3 files:

```
101m.frm -- The schema (see  SHOW CREATE TABLE 101m;)
101m.MYD -- The rows of data.
101m.MYI -- The indexes.  If lost or damaged, `REPAIR` will rebuild it.
```

Comment: Yeah, I did that. But I thought its wrong. Its loading since ≈ 6h now and wont do anything then loading. Is it because its 19gb? I guess so

Comment: The load could be faster -- skip the `.MYI` since the `REPAIR` builds it from scratch anyway.

Comment: Its still going btw.
How do I skip it? isnt it needed for the database?
im very sorry for all the questions. Im very new to mysql

Comment: (I added more..)

Comment: yeah, but the MYI is damaged so i have to repair it. Its still going lol

Comment: after more then 12h loading I got this error.
``Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Dbal\DbiMysqli.php on line 209``

I can still open the database and click threw any row but if I search for a certain id it will show this error: 
#126 - Index for table '.\chris\101m.MYI' is corrupt; try to repair it

Comment: Sounds like either PHP or MySQL has a time-limit.

Comment: so there is no way for me to recover then paying 250€ for StellarRepairForMySQL? I would pay but not 250€.

Comment: If you still have the .frm and .MYD, up the time limits and run `REPAIR` again.  No 250€ needed.